# displaying the rows with empty values in some columns of the table

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rows

I am creating an app where the user needs to fill a form.
I need to fetch the rows in which some specific columns are empty and display it to the user.
i can get the count of the no.of rows by

```
Cursor appcount=db.rawQuery("select count(app_salutation) AS appempty from "+AllValuesTable+" where app_salutation=''", null);
    appcount.moveToFirst();
    int apco=appcount.getInt(0);
    appcount.close();
```

now i want to display these rows which have some empty feilds.
how do i do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</ListLayout> 
</Scrollable>
```

Layout and put inside it ListLayout

using this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/316690/Custom-list-item-layout